# When and when not specializing template instances

Tags: c++

I have just learn a few pages about templates and have the following problem.
`A.h`

```
struct A
{
   template<class T> T func();
};
```

`A.cpp`

```
template<class T>
T func()
{
   //do something
}

template<> int A::func<int>();
template<> char A::func<char>();
```

Now if I have this struct

```
template<class C>
struct B
{
    template<typename T>
    T func();
};
```

Will I have to write out all cases when `func` is to be used with what specific `class C` ?

```
e.g 
template<classX> int func<int>();
template<classX> char func<char>();
template<classY> int func<int>();
....
```

Comment: Why are you enumerating all the possible uses *in either case*? That entirely negates the point of having template functions.

Comment: If the amount of specialisation is growing exponentially, then you are most likely trying to solve a problem (using templates) that requires a different solution.  This feels like an XY-problem.  What is the underlying issue that you want to solve with templates?

Comment: If you move the implementations to the header file (or a file that is included in), no.

Comment: I leave it in `.cpp` for the sake of beauty. Now you enlighten me that it sux that way. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: If you don't like having it in the *same* file as the declarations, what I usually do is put my template implementations in a `.tcc` file and include that at the bottom of the header. To the compiler, it's the same effect, but now to the developer it looks like it's in two separate files.

Comment: "I leave it in .cpp for the sake of beauty." What? If you split definition and declaration your optimizer has no chance to get all possible optimizations done, simply because the compiler don't see the complete picture. As a hammer on that problem you can switch on link time optimzer, ok. But it is less common to split definitions from declarations in C++ than in C! You should think again of "beauty" and see more the technical aspects!